# Unexpected character in wdqs-updater_1 upon restart of a Wikibase

Tags: wikibase

When working with a local Wikibase I noticed that the autocomplete function stopped working in the local query service. After a shutdown and startup I get the following message:

```
...
Stopping phenowiki_wdqs_1            ... done
...

./startup.sh

Starting phenowiki_wdqs_1          ... done
Starting phenowiki_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Starting phenowiki_mysql_1         ... done
Starting phenowiki_wdqs-proxy_1      ... done
Starting phenowiki_wikibase_1      ... done
Starting phenowiki_quickstatements_1 ... done
Starting phenowiki_wdqs-updater_1    ... done
Starting phenowiki_wdqs-frontend_1   ... done
Attaching to phenowiki_wdqs_1, phenowiki_elasticsearch_1, phenowiki_mysql_1, phenowiki_wikibase_1, phenowiki_wdqs-updater_1, phenowiki_quickstatements_1, phenowiki_wdqs-proxy_1, phenowiki_wdqs-frontend_1
wdqs_1             | /wdqs /wdqs
wdqs_1             | Running Blazegraph from /wdqs on :9999/bigdata
wdqs_1             | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/wdqs/wdqs-blazegraph_jvm_gc.pid7-2019-07-12_07-54-42.log due to No such file or directory
wdqs_1             |
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:42.564:INFO::main: Logging initialized @166ms
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:44,800][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:42.571:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:42.659:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.3.v20140905
wikibase_1         | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 120 seconds for mysql.svc:3306
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:47.605:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
wikibase_1         | wait-for-it.sh: mysql.svc:3306 is available after 0 seconds
wikibase_1         | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 120 seconds for mysql.svc:3306
wdqs_1             | #logback.classic pattern: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} IP:%X{req.remoteHost} UA:%X{req.userAgent} - %msg%n
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:44,903][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [5sOo-00] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/nvme0n1p2)]], net usable_space [297.7gb], net total_space [878.6gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:44,903][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [5sOo-00] heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.16-MariaDB-1:10.3.16+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
wikibase_1         | wait-for-it.sh: mysql.svc:3306 is available after 0 seconds
wikibase_1         | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 60 seconds for elasticsearch.svc:9200
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
quickstatements_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.80.7. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wdqs_1             | INFO: com.bigdata.util.config.LogUtil: Configure: file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9999-blazegraph-service-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_bigdata-any-1586101280383644326.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties
wdqs-updater_1     | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 120 seconds for myserver.nl:80
wdqs_1             | 07:54:48.105 [main] WARN  com.bigdata.Banner IP: UA: - Defaulting log level to WARN: com.bigdata
quickstatements_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.80.7. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wdqs_1             |
wdqs_1             | BlazeGraph(TM) Graph Engine
wdqs_1             |
wdqs_1             |                    Flexible
wdqs_1             |                    Reliable
wdqs_1             |                   Affordable
wdqs_1             |       Web-Scale Computing for the Enterprise
wdqs_1             |
wdqs_1             | Copyright SYSTAP, LLC DBA Blazegraph 2006-2016.  All rights reserved.
wdqs_1             |
wdqs_1             | 1a307070fc17
wdqs_1             | Fri Jul 12 07:54:48 GMT 2019
wdqs_1             | Linux/4.15.0-50-generic amd64
wdqs_1             | Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU @ 2.20GHz Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel #CPU=40
wdqs_1             | IcedTea 1.8.0_212
wdqs_1             | freeMemory=642250776
wdqs_1             | buildVersion=2.1.5-SNAPSHOT
wdqs_1             | gitCommit=8ff64aab6071b5e591e80676809e43f0ddb8ad49
wdqs_1             |
wdqs_1             | Dependency         License
wdqs_1             | ICU                http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/license.html
wdqs_1             | bigdata-ganglia    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | blueprints-core    https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
wdqs_1             | colt               http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/license.html
wdqs_1             | commons-codec      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | commons-fileupload http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | commons-io         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | commons-logging    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | dsiutils           http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html
wdqs_1             | fastutil           http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | flot               http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
wdqs_1             | high-scale-lib     http://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain
wdqs_1             | httpclient         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | httpclient-cache   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | httpcore           http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | httpmime           http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | jackson-core       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | jetty              http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | jquery             https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt
wdqs_1             | jsonld             https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java/master/LICENCE
wdqs_1             | log4j              http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | lucene             http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | nanohttp           http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/#license
wdqs_1             | rexster-core       https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
wdqs_1             | river              http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | semargl            https://github.com/levkhomich/semargl/blob/master/LICENSE
wdqs_1             | servlet-api        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             | sesame             http://www.openrdf.org/download.jsp
wdqs_1             | slf4j              http://www.slf4j.org/license.html
wdqs_1             | zookeeper          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
wdqs_1             |
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
wdqs-updater_1     | wait-for-it.sh: myserver.nl:80 is available after 0 seconds
quickstatements_1  | [Fri Jul 12 07:54:48.712372 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/5.6.40 configured -- resuming normal operations
quickstatements_1  | [Fri Jul 12 07:54:48.712425 2019] [core:notice] [pid 11] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
wdqs_1             | 07:54:49.105 [main] WARN  com.bigdata.rdf.ServiceProviderHook IP: UA: - Running.
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:44,921][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [5sOo-00] derived from node ID [5sOo-00hTAC1FV3BKuzvxA]; set [node.name] to override
wdqs-updater_1     | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 120 seconds for wdqs.svc:9999
wdqs_1             | 07:54:49.159 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.b.mwapi.MWApiServiceFactory IP: UA: - Loading MWAPI service configuration from ./mwservices.json
wdqs_1             | 07:54:49.537 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.b.mwapi.MWApiServiceFactory IP: UA: - Registered 4 services.
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:44,922][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.6.14], pid[1], build[f310fe9/2018-12-05T21:20:16.416Z], OS[Linux/4.15.0-50-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_181/25.181-b13]
wdqs-updater_1     | wait-for-it.sh: wdqs.svc:9999 is available after 3 seconds
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:44,922][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch]
wdqs-updater_1     | Updating via http://wdqs.svc:9999/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [ingest-common]
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
wdqs-updater_1     | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/wdqs/wdqs-updater_jvm_gc.pid7.log due to No such file or directory
wdqs-updater_1     |
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [lang-expression]
wdqs-updater_1     | I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [lang-groovy]
wdqs-updater_1     | Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://127.0.0.1:8778/jolokia/
wdqs_1             | 07:54:49.555 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.b.WikibaseContextListener IP: UA: - Wikibase services initialized.
wdqs_1             | 07:54:49.642 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.b.t.ThrottlingFilter IP: UA: - ThrottlingFilter MBean registered as org.wikidata.query.rdf.blazegraph.throttling.ThrottlingFilter:filterName=throttling-filter.
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,984][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [lang-mustache]
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:49.681:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2d363fb3{/bigdata,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-9999-blazegraph-service-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_bigdata-any-1586101280383644326.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/wdqs/blazegraph-service-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war}
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
wdqs-updater_1     | #logback.classic pattern: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [lang-painless]
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [parent-join]
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:49.682:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [percolator]
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:49.693:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@46e8a539{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9999}
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [reindex]
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
wdqs_1             | 2019-07-12 07:54:49.696:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @7339ms
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [transport-netty3]
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded module [transport-netty4]
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:45,985][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5sOo-00] loaded plugin [extra]
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:46,148][WARN ][o.e.d.s.ScriptModule     ] Native scripts are deprecated. Use a custom ScriptEngine to write scripts in java.
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:47,312][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [5sOo-00] using discovery type [zen]
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:48,064][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:48,065][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [5sOo-00] starting ...
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:48,207][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [5sOo-00] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 6230267; transaction id 2553
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@c16b13b97f72' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1            | Version: '10.3.16-MariaDB-1:10.3.16+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
mysql_1            | 2019-07-12  7:54:45 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190712  7:54:45
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:51,287][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [5sOo-00] new_master {5sOo-00}{5sOo-00hTAC1FV3BKuzvxA}{tfRuBuVIToaQhhqABeBQEg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:51,343][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [5sOo-00] publish_address {192.168.80.3:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:51,344][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [5sOo-00] started
wdqs-updater_1     | 07:54:51.561 [main] INFO  org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update - Checking where we left off
wdqs-updater_1     | 07:54:51.563 [main] INFO  o.w.query.rdf.tool.rdf.RdfRepository - Checking for left off time from the updater
wdqs-updater_1     | 07:54:52.111 [main] INFO  o.w.query.rdf.tool.rdf.RdfRepository - Checking for left off time from the dump
wdqs-updater_1     | 07:54:52.149 [main] INFO  org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update - Defaulting start time to 90 days ago:  2019-04-13T07:54:52Z
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:52,178][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [5sOo-00] recovered [3] indices into cluster_state
wikibase_1         | wait-for-it.sh: elasticsearch.svc:9200 is available after 5 seconds
wdqs-updater_1     | 07:54:52.324 [main] ERROR org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update - Error during updater run.
wdqs-updater_1     | java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
wdqs-updater_1     |  at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:270)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.fetchRecentChanges(RecentChangesPoller.java:301)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.batch(RecentChangesPoller.java:314)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.firstBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:139)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.firstBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:33)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater.run(Updater.java:125)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update.main(Update.java:80)
wdqs-updater_1     | Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
wdqs-updater_1     |  at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1798)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:663)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:561)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2625)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:826)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:723)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4129)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3058)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.getJson(WikibaseRepository.java:422)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:264)
wdqs-updater_1     |    ... 6 common frames omitted
wdqs-updater_1     | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
wdqs-updater_1     |  at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:270)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.fetchRecentChanges(RecentChangesPoller.java:301)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.batch(RecentChangesPoller.java:314)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.firstBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:139)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.firstBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:33)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater.run(Updater.java:125)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update.main(Update.java:80)
wdqs-updater_1     | Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
wdqs-updater_1     |  at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1798)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:663)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:561)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2625)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:826)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:723)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4129)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3988)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3058)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.getJson(WikibaseRepository.java:422)
wdqs-updater_1     |    at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:264)
wdqs-updater_1     |    ... 6 more
wikibase_1         | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.80.6. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wikibase_1         | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.80.6. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wikibase_1         | [Fri Jul 12 07:54:52.423218 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 59] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.2.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
wikibase_1         | [Fri Jul 12 07:54:52.423284 2019] [core:notice] [pid 59] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
phenowiki_wdqs-updater_1 exited with code 1
elasticsearch_1    | [2019-07-12T07:54:53,079][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [5sOo-00] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[mw_cirrus_metastore_first][0]] ...]).
Update finished
wikibase_1         | 10.2.0.24 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:57:36 +0000] "GET /wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2&peek=1&from=20190712075407&isAnon=true&action=render HTTP/1.1" 204 472 "http://myserver.nl:8181/wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"
wikibase_1         | 10.2.0.24 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:57:36 +0000] "GET /wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 8081 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"
wikibase_1         | 10.2.0.24 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:57:37 +0000] "POST /w/api.php HTTP/1.1" 200 923 "http://myserver.nl:8181/wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"
wikibase_1         | 10.2.0.24 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:57:37 +0000] "POST /w/api.php HTTP/1.1" 200 924 "http://myserver.nl:8181/wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"
wikibase_1         | 10.2.0.24 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:57:37 +0000] "GET /w/opensearch_desc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 793 "-" "com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper/14607.2.6.1.1 CFNetwork/978.0.7 Darwin/18.6.0 (x86_64)"
wikibase_1         | 10.2.0.24 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:58:54 +0000] "GET /wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2&peek=1&from=20190712075737&isAnon=true&action=render HTTP/1.1" 204 472 "http://myserver.nl:8181/wiki/Special:RecentChanges?hidebots=1&hideWikibase=1&limit=50&days=7&enhanced=1&urlversion=2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"
wdqs-proxy_1       | 192.168.80.9 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:59:29 +0000] "GET /bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?query=prefix%20schema:%20%3Chttp://schema.org/%3E%20SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%3Chttp://www.wikidata.org%3E%20schema:dateModified%20?y%7D&nocache=26048639 HTTP/1.0" 200 83 "http://myserver.nl:8282/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
wdqs-frontend_1    | 10.2.0.24 - - [12/Jul/2019:07:59:29 +0000] "GET /proxy/wdqs/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?query=prefix%20schema:%20%3Chttp://schema.org/%3E%20SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%3Chttp://www.wikidata.org%3E%20schema:dateModified%20?y%7D&nocache=26048639 HTTP/1.1" 200 94 "http://myserver.nl:8282/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
```

Is anyone familiar on how this could have happend? I managed to reproduce this problem by starting from a clean docker based Wikibase after startup I did a shutdown and then start it up again.

Comment: I am getting this error too if I use a custom LocalSettings.php as described here: https://addshore.com/2018/06/customizing-wikibase-config-in-the-docker-compose-example/ @addshore

Comment: I have created a startup script and I had not encountered this problem since. https://pastebin.com/7Mw4wSat

Comment: Thanks for checking back. I started over and that error went away. One comment regarding your startup script though: You might consider using the "volume mount" feature (see the link in my previous comment) for all those files you `docker cp` in there. I tend to prefer tracking the files in my own repo and mounting them in docker-compose.yml as mentioned.